# Chesss training-Can’t find the proper white move

Tags: analysis, training

I'm really struggling to find the proper white move. Can someone help me? Also, is there some tool to assist training?

```
[Title "White to move"]
[fen "2k3rr/pbpp4/1pn1p4/8/2PPB1qp/2N1P2Q/PP4P1/2R2RK1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Rf8+ wins pretty much instantly. You could download a chess engine but that will not in any way help you with your training.

Comment: You could also download tactics training software as the above question clearly indicates that you are missing tactical shots that are not that hard to see if you've done a little practice.  There are tons of free tactics servers to practice with, but building your tactical muscles in a more holistic way would require you to diligently store missed-shot positions like the above into custom-training software like ChessHero (http://innokuo.altervista.org/chesshero.html) where you can practice/review and drill these out daily/weekly until you start seeing these shots or "blindspots" instantly.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is **1.Rf8+**, as Cleveland commented. You remove the defender of the queen on g4 (that is, the rook on g8) by distracting it.

```
[FEN "2k3rr/pbpp4/1pn1p3/8/2PPB1qp/2N1P2Q/PP4P1/2R2RK1 w - - 0 1"]

1.Rf8+ Rxf8 {1...Nd8 2.Qxg4 Rxg4 3.Bxb7+ Kxb7 4.Rxh8} 2.Qxg4
```

Wins the black queen in exchange for a rook, which means that white is winning. If black doesn't take the rook and instead blocks the check with 1...Nd8, white exchanges queens with 2.Qxg4 Rxg4, then exchanges bishops on b7 with check (3.Bxb7+ Kxb7) because the bishop was attacked twice, and then wins the rook on h8 (4.Rxh8).

As for training tools, workbooks that explain a tactical theme and then give a number of exercises is the usual way, e.g. the Steps Method. A good website like that is [Predator at the Chessboard](http://www.chesstactics.org/), where a tactic like this could fit in chapter 5.2.